# Access Ant Design table column value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am trying to condionally render Bage based on status column value. Even though I can render the table with the status values, I cannot access the status column for each item  for conditional rendering of status Badge. How do I access the values listed on the column ?
The "status" value is inside data [ ]

```
const tableColumns = columns.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    ellipsis,
  }));

 const columns = [
{
      title: 'Статус',
      dataIndex: 'status',
      render: () =>   {dataIndex.status === "in progress" ?  <Badge status="processing" text="in progress" /> : <Badge status="success" text="delivered" />}
    },
]


 <Table
        {...tableProps}
        pagination={{
          position: [top, bottom],
        }}
        columns={tableColumns}
        dataSource={hasData ? data : []}
        scroll={scroll}
      />
```

Comment: Can you please give more information about `dataIndex`?

Comment: Am actually beginner, just getting started with Ant Design UI framework. As it says in documentation (https://2x.ant.design/components/table/#) dataIndex : Displays field of the data record.

Comment: the render() function that I am using inside Column was also documented : render () : Function(text, record, index) {}. But I don't still quite get how can I compare items status

Comment: Tell me about the `data` that you want to pass it to `dataSource` table prop? If you could attach that to the question content, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: yes, I have my data ( array of objects ) inside const data [ ] and I assign it to dataSource while creating the <Table/>. My apologies for not being able to clearly explain the problem, because I am still figuring out the framework myself.

Comment: So If you want, I assume an object for  `data` and answer your question based on it.

Comment: `dataIndex` is simple way to render any plain value by passing the key name. e.g. `status`. But you want to render jsx based on some conditional logic, use `render`. `render` pass 3 args. You can render the badge like this by getting status from second arg. `render: (val, row, index) => row?.status === "in progress" ?  <Badge status="processing" text="in progress" /> : <Badge status="success" text="delivered" />`.